# "Error in error handling" when calling lua function from C++

Tags: c++, lua

This is not about how to call a lua function from C++. I can already do that successfully. This is about the lua function "loadfile" no longer working when used in a function called by C++.

I'm trying to load a lua file into another lua file so that I can call its functions. If I move test() from functions.lua to game.lua, *mystring* receives "test" just fine.

However, when I add the init() function to the game.lua file and move test() to the functions.lua file:

1. loadfile no longer seems to work, producing "error in error handling"
2. calling test() doesn't work (probably due to the failed loadfile) which also results in a "error in error handling" message.

**C++:**

```
// Having loaded game.lua...
state["init"]();
std::string mystring = state["test"]();
```

**game.lua:**

```
function init()
    loadfile("functions.lua")()
end
```

**functions.lua:**

```
function test()
  return "test"
end
```

**Error:**

```
"Error in error handling"
```

When I use ZeroBrane to test this Lua script by simply doing:

```
init()
print(test())
```

It all works fine... so there's something wrong with how I'm either using C++ or using the lua file.

What am I doing wrong here? Why doesn't loadfile seem to work when used in this manner? Does lua not get initialized to the point of seeing its regular functions with started by C++? Really strange how loadfile works via ZeroBrane but not from C++.

I'm using [Selene](https://github.com/jeremyong/Selene), a C++11 header-only bindings to Lua.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to establish the lua context!

**Establishing Lua Context**

```
using namespace sel;
State state; // creates a Lua context
State state{true}; // creates a Lua context and loads standard Lua libraries
```